# how to handle errors using try catch in a dropdownlist inside a detailsview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, edit, detailsview

I have a dropdownlist inside a detailsview where I will be editing records inside the details view. My problem is dropdownlist inside the details view is bind to a field and giving an error

> 'DropDownList1' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does
>   not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

This is due to the selectedvalue value is not in the dropdownlist.

Can someone tell me how to handle this error. I want to use try catch and do nothing and just ignore the error or maybe pass a blank value as selectedvalue in the dropdown.

Main problem I have is I am not sure where to put the try catch statement.

Complete code is below.

```
   <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        DataKeyNames="RecordRef" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" Height="50px" 
        Width="125px">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecordRef" HeaderText="RecordRef" ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="RecordRef" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
                SortExpression="CustomerID" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="JobCategory" SortExpression="JobCategory">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                        DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" DataTextField="ItemValue" 
                        DataValueField="ItemValue" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("JobCategory") %>'>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="name=CRMSEntities" DefaultContainerName="CRMSEntities2" 
                        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="KeyValues">
                    </asp:EntityDataSource>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobCategory") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("JobCategory") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobDescription" HeaderText="JobDescription" 
                SortExpression="JobDescription" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobDate" HeaderText="JobDate" 
                SortExpression="JobDate" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="JobStatus" HeaderText="JobStatus" 
                SortExpression="JobStatus" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Referral" HeaderText="Referral" 
                SortExpression="Referral" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle exception with override OnRender method of your usercontrol with using try catch around base.Render

Comment: And on global.asax you can also captures them - and then ? The issue here is to capture it, ignore it and continue to render the GridView.

Comment: Ye you can handle all exception in global.asax,also you can handle it on parent control, or just you can handle it within custom base class...@Aristos thanks I will be complete my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Try ... Catch, you could use the following in code behind (VB in this case):

```
Dim ddlItem As ListItem
ddlItem = myDDL.Items.FindByValue(UserInput.ToString())
If Not ddlItem Is Nothing Then
    ddlItem.Selected = True
Else
    myDDL.Text = "Some text to indicate failure"
End If
```